# Getting table from mysql database to fill datalist

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, database, datalist

Until now I did successfully take values from database. My problem is not being able to fill data in datalist as table. My code to get simple values is the following:

```
try
   {
    using (OdbcConnection connection = new OdbcConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MySQLConnStr"].ConnectionString))
       {
           connection.Open();
           using (OdbcCommand command = new OdbcCommand("SELECT * FROM datas", connection))
            using (OdbcDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader())
             {
                while (dr.Read())
                 {
                     switch (dr["namen"].ToString())
                      {
                          case "gt": Label2.Text = dr["dest"].ToString(); break;
                          case "gp1": Image1.ImageUrl = dr["dest"].ToString(); break;
                          case "gp2": Image2.ImageUrl = dr["dest"].ToString(); break;
                          case "gp3": Image3.ImageUrl = dr["dest"].ToString(); break;
                       }
                 }
                    dr.Close();
              }
                connection.Close();
          }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write("An error occured: " + ex.Message);
        }
```

Comment: Just a couple tips. 1) Use the [MySQL DotNet Connector](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/) and 2) Don't do `select *`.

Comment: What exactly is the problem?  Are you getting an error?  Where is the code to populate the datalist?

Comment: i need a way to get data as table so i can bind it to datalist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use DataAdapter , fill it to datatable

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/358631/how-to-bind-data-from-sql-server-to-datalist-using

```
List <string> datalist1 = new List<string>();

datalist1.DataSource = _dtTable1;

datalist1.DataBind();
```